# Should independent tag wiki edits be separated?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I recently did my first tag wiki edits, which made me wonder if bigger(read: independent from each other) changes to a tag wiki should be separately suggested.

Consider the following case: 
I want to edit multiple larger sections of a tag wiki (Take the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) wiki as an example). Those edits would change/add/remove content from multiple places inside the wiki. Each of those edits would however make sense on it's own.

These changes would end up to be reviewed as I don't have the rep to directly edit a tag wiki.
If I had them committed in one bigger edit a reviewer might come to the conclusion that only a part of my suggested edit should end up in the tag wiki. To my current knowledge he has then the following options:

- Reject the edit and do nothing, leaving potential good content go away
- Reject and edit the better parts himself into the tag wiki
- Accept and remove the part he considered bad from the tag wiki himself
- Accept and hope that someone else will handle it

On the other hand if I suggested multiple smaller edits he could reject the unwanted edit and approve the better one and would be done with that.

This options leaves however the question if I might be flagged for repeated suggested edits on this tag wiki (I don't see a option to mark that edits belong together or that I don't want reputation for a suggested edit) or if it would be considered bad behaviour to fill up the review queue in this way.

Comment: You can explain your edit in the edit summary.

Comment: option 2 (reject+edit) and option 3 (accept+edit) are VERY RARE on tag wiki suggestions because it requires both 20 000 reputation and an interest in the tag. So de-facto, when a tag-wiki edit isn't near perfect, it is ignored and often rejected.

Answer (score 3):

You plan to make a large tag wiki edit.

It is *reasonable* to submit a single/composite edit, and you have asserted that you could *reasonably* break the edit down into smaller pieces each of which would "make sense on [their] own". Therefore, with two reasonable paths open to you, how to proceed is a judgement call.

These observations ought to help you make the right decision depending on the circumstances:

- In my experience, it takes 24 hours or more to get an outcome on a
  single tag wiki edit. You would have to wait for your first edit to be approved before you could make the second. This also means you won't be "filling up" the review queue.
- **Each suggested edit will take up the valuable time of 1-3 reviewers.**
- The bar is quite high for tag wiki edits. Reviewers are particularly on the lookout for copied content and risk a review ban if they [fail to spot it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344937/397817), and for [usage guidance to be present](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364109/397817). You have to jump that bar every time you submit an edit suggestion.
- Trivial edits which leave other issues in the post [should be rejected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251659/397817). Don't do this! On the other hand, yes, you risk rejection of your entire large edit if reviewers object to any part of it, but we can take steps to minimise that risk (see below).
- Reviewing tag wiki edits is a [5k privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). Editing tag wikis without needing approval is a [20k privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). Therefore there is a strong chance your edit will be reviewed by people who have to choose between "Approve" and "Reject", with [no "Improve" option](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268259/397817). An "Approve & edit" on a tag wiki is a rare thing in the wild.

My advice would be to value your time and that of reviewers, and always favour one-hit edits. This also reduces your exposure to risk. Under very limited circumstances, where part of your edit is particularly bold (such as removing irrelevant material), then feel free to break it down into 2 edits.

Whichever route you decide to take be sure to add a thorough (but concise!) edit summary, detailing the changes you made and why you made them. And of course, do not copy from Wikipedia or promotional blurb or from anywhere else without attribution - better still, don't copy from other places *at all*. Tailor the content to Stack Overflow, detail how the tag should be used, and try to avoid information which dates easily - such as a list of version numbers and release dates - unless relevant to tag usage on this site.

If you do that your edit(s) will likely - although not certainly - be approved.