# Option to "Improve" a suggested edit to a tag wiki entry?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

When reviewing suggested edits to tag wiki entries, I sometimes come across cases where the bulk of the edit is legitimate and helpful, but there are additional improvements that would be trivially easy to make.

To give a *very* trivial example:

[image]

The bulk of this edit looks like an improvement, but it would be nice to fix the capitalization on the first line. Other common minor issues are spelling/grammatical errors, proper formatting of URLs etc.

If this were a suggested edit to a question or an answer, I would jump in and "Improve" the suggested edit, but I don't have the option to do that with tag wiki entries. I can only either accept the edit as is, or reject it and suggest my own, which is more hassle for me and seems unfair to the user who initially suggested the edit.

Is there some particular reason why we can't have an option to "Improve" a suggested edit to a tag wiki entry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have enough reputation to directly edit tag wikis without approval. That privilege isn't given to you until you reach 20,000 reputation. So, you attempting to Improve a suggested edit on a tag wiki would itself create another suggested edit. If you have improvements to make, you have to wait until that one is either approved or rejected.

At 20,000 reputation, you **do** get an Improve button for tag wikis and excerpts.

Comment: I see. There's still a real problem with the quality of wiki tag edits that get approved, and I think the fact that there is no straightforward way for a <20K reviewer to improve on an existing edit is a contributing factor. Would it make sense to introduce a mechanism where reviewers can see all of the current suggested edits to a particular tag wiki entry, and select the one that looks the most appropriate? The Improve option could then be re-introduced for <20K users, where it would create a new suggested edit.

Comment: I don't think the Stack Exchange team is interested in completely rewriting how the suggested edit system works.

Comment: I just ran into this, too, for http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9407175 (for http://stackoverflow.com/tags/armclang/info).  I looks genrally good, but is missing the word "a".  What if future reviewers saw just the latest edit, but with edit history?  So if there was something wrong with the version you see, you could rollback and approve a previous good version (which maybe already had some approve votes).  I just approved the edit, even though it needs improvement, since it's better than nothing.  I might or might not bother to come back and check later and suggest a new edit.

Comment: Is there a good reason why reviews of wiki tag edits are allowed by users with under 20K rep.   Assuming that if a user had over 20K rep, the wiki tag edits where the first edit review tasks in their review queue.

Comment: This happens to me all the time. I end up just approving things which have spelling mistakes (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15821848) because it seems better than rejecting them.