# 6 day ban for review of wiki tag?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

I understand the [review bans are progressive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256231/608639). Is a six day ban expected with two failed audits in several weeks and no bans in the last year or so:

[image]

Related, how did this ban arrive? As far as I know, there are audits on wiki tags. Is it an arbitrary punishment by a moderator?

Comment: FYI - the progressive review ban info you linked too is outdated.  The new logic is detailed in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days

Answer (score 14):

The system doesn't currently leave such detailed guidance; this would've had to be a moderator. Tag wiki plagiarizing has been a persistent problem, so please be extra-skeptical when reviewing these in the future (usually a quick Google search will turn up the source if there's a significant amount of added text).

Comment: Thanks. *"...this would've had to be a moderator..."* - why six days? *"usually a quick Google search will turn up the source if there's a significant amount of added text..."* - if its a problem, then it seems like the system should be performing the step to avoid the problem. Are there any reasons the system is not performing the step to control the problem?

Comment: @jww Your questions were already [discussed in the previous meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341327/banned-for-failing-to-recognize-check-for-plagiarism-1st-time-draconian) where that OP had got a 7 day ban as well. Usually the first ban for plagiarism approvals is 7 days.

Comment: Thanks Bhargav. Out of morbid curiosity, what project or company has complained their project description was used on Stack Overflow? I've got a feeling some folks are trying to identify a problem where one does not exist.

Comment: @jww if you read the [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts), you will notice that the tag wiki's are meant to offer guidance about the tag itself, not just the thing it represents. Also, content duplication is a big nono if we want the tag wiki's to ever appear in search engines.