# Serial rejection of my suggested edits

Tags: support, rejected-edits

I'm no longer able to suggest edits. I'm getting the following error:

> Too many of your edits were rejected.

I read the reasons and I'll take them under consideration next time I write a wiki excerpt.

Still, I found that lately I was rejected by the same user over and over again.

If I'm down voted by a specific user, I used to flag the post as *in need of moderator intervention* and wrote my concerns and sometimes a moderator did undo the serial down voting.

Can I be considered to be serially rejected?

These rejections are only from last week from the same user (while others may have approved):

- Rejected edit - rejected by the same user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18970495), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18998578), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18998357), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18974382), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18951033) (1 approval), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18946646) (1 approval).
- Approved edit - 2 approvals and 1 reject by the same user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18950334), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18974491), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18933430), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18926973).

Comment: There are not that many users that review wiki edits, so running into the same reviewers repeatedly is not a surprise.  Many reviewers quit reviewing them after they got banned for not noticing plagiarism.  You are wasting your time with these one-liner edit proposals, they'll be rejected with a boilerplate reject reason every time.  Look at the wikis of established tags to see what is expected.

Comment: I suspect the [tag wiki/excerpt FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one) might help more.

Comment: not directly related: reading your answers to questions also shows some missunderstanding about how this site works. Your latest answers are to questions which should have better be closed as too broad/unclear or otherwise off-topic. With >9k reputation, you are expected to follow site-rules and help keep the quality of this site high. You have some moderation privileges, so use them. off-topic questions  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Chronicle Queue - a Micro second messaging that stores everything to disk

plagiarised from [here](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue)

> GdkPixbuf is a library for image loading and manipulation

plagiarised from [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/)

> libssl is the portion of OpenSSL which supports TLS

plagiarised from [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libssl_API)

Presumably some of the others are too. Reviewers are supposed to check the [following points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits):

> - All the content is original or attributed properly
> - Wiki excerpts are concise and contain an objective description of the tag

which is precisely what they seem to have done. So given that they all should be rejected and you should be banned, the fact that there's someone who's often involved is rather missing the point.

If you keep driving past a speed camera and keep getting speeding tickets, the answer is not to blame the speed camera, the answer is **stop speeding**.

Answer (score 21):

Around 50% of the edits shown here are clear plagiarism where you copied text from the website / GitHub page of the libraries. (There are more of them than the reject messages show.)

All of these edits just say what the tag is about, but don't contain any guideline on how the tag should be used.

Finally, some of them contain typos, wrong grammar, or missing punctuation. For example:

> Java WS is **a** Java API for XML Web Services.

Conclusion: The rejections of your edits seems to be perfectly fine. I, for myself would, in addition for rejecting, also have custom flagged for continued plagiarism.

Comment: _"All of these edits just say what the tag is about, but don't contain any guideline on how the tag should be used."_, this is the answer. Helping others to use our categorisation system effectively is the _primary_ purpose. Any secondary uses can go in the wiki itself