# When to check "Suggested edit was helpful"?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

When reviewing edits, the Improve option presents the reviewer with an editor view that has this checkbox, labeled "suggested edit was helpful" and checked by default.

When should this be unchecked? Does "helpful", in this case, mean "improving the post in any way" or should I limit checking the box to edits I would've approved, given the choice between Approve and Reject?

For example, if an edit fixes a typo or two while leaving many untouched and failing to fix the formatting problem, it is too minor and should either be rejected or improved. If I improve on that, should I tick the box or not?

Comment: if it fixes one or two out of say 10+ then it is not helpful(too minor). If it missed 1 or 2 then it was helpful

Answer (score 4):

> When should this be unchecked?

**Almost never.**

If you're setting out to improve an edit you don't think was helpful, you should probably stop and ask yourself why you aren't just *rejecting* it. On Stack Overflow, the vast majority of edits are processed in minutes, and you'll likely spend more time undoing the damage done by the editor whose edit you're improving than you would've just rejecting the edit and grabbing a snack before returning to make a proper edit. [OGHaza outlines some exceptions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265180/811), but... If you have to think about it... It's probably not worth doing.

Use "improve" for those situations where the edit is reasonably helpful, but you see more that could be done.

Comment: Good answer otherwise, but you seem to make a bad assumption that when I improve on someone's edit, it's to "undo the damage done by the editor" while 99% of the time (at least for me) it's doing the corrections the original editor should've done in the first place; the typos/formatting problems they missed, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I uncheck the box for any edit I would have rejected had I not decided to improve.

Generally this means it's because the edit was "too minor" - since I'm unlikely to improve an edit is inappropriate for one of the other reasons.

There has been a lot of discussion over what is considered "too minor", everyone has their own opinion, see:

- [“Too minor” edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)
- [What is wrong with minor edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits) - top voted answer is Quantas's breakdown of why he considers a particular edit too minor.
- and their [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253123/when-an-edit-only-fixes-a-typo-what-should-i-do-as-a-reviewer?rq=1) [posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251658/what-to-do-with-a-user-making-many-minor-changes?rq=1). Surprisingly couldn't find as much discussion as I expected - maybe on meta.SE?

For me, if I feel their edit left any major glaring mistakes or left a number of small mistakes - such that my "improvement" feels like the bulk of the edit with their contribution as an addendum rather than the other way around, I'll uncheck the box.