# User is making repeated trivial edits that don't fix all changes

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

A [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821093/delimitry) is by appearance submitting A LOT of useless trivial edits, many of which are fixing one or two typos in a post, usually to no real benefit, and usually leaving many OTHER typos left that I've had to fix up.  I noticed after improving a couple of his/her proposed edits that it was the same person again and again.  If you just look at his recent activity you can see he/she has maxed out or nearly so the daily rep increase for editing the past three days. And nearly all of them were one or two word changes.

Is this now accepted behavior on StackOverflow?

Here is a sample:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8209994

While I could take the trivial answer and 'skip' that just kicks the can down the road and solves nothing and renders no point to posting... So let's assume skip isn't a choice for the sake of discussion.

As a new 'edit reviewer' and in light of the recent change in rules regarding minor edits, what should I be doing here?  I'm getting tired of correcting every single item he misses; I feel like rejecting flat out isn't right (anymore.... weeks ago I would have rejected as that is behavior I learned from meta discussions).  I feel like accept and improving each time rewards his blatant rep hoarding effort.  Accepting without improving doesn't feel right at all..

So besides posting here to ask this question; what's my best course of action?

Comment: So why don't you want to reject the inappropriate edit that you know is inappropriate?  I mean I understand the despair that everyone else approves the edits anyway, but the fact that most reviewers approve bad edits, while sad, doesn't exactly make it unclear what to do when you see a bad edit.

Comment: because it's not technically inappropriate / bad. There's nothing WRONG with the edit. There are just additional things he missed.  Based on reading the other thread, we aren't supposed to reject as 'too minor' anymore. What would the reject reason be?   Seems like it would be a good medium if they only got 1 point when we had to improve their edit.

Comment: 'top 0.07% overall' on edits.  Impressive:(

Comment: @UpAndAdam The rejection reason would be exactly the reason listed in the example edit you showed.

Comment: @MartinJames top .07% *for the week*, not overall.

Comment: "don't fix all changes" Fix the changes?

Comment: Oh, the controversy. While I would personally reject such an edit, I think it's fair to point out that the time spent reviewing is proportional to the time spent editing. A simple typo correction should take about 5 seconds to review.

Answer (score 21):

These suggested edits don't come at no cost. Sure, these might make a tiny, trivial improvement to posts but they cost the time of three reviewers who have to read and approve or deny them. If someone is not going to put in the effort to make a non-trivial amount of improvement to a post, they should **not** be sending that an edit to the Suggested Edits queue.

The Suggested Edits are held to a different level of scrutiny than edits where the user has full privileges. If you're making a suggested edit, it should be because the post **needs it** - not because you feel like making three reviewers approve one typo fix on a post that genuinely needs more thorough attention. The point of the suggested edits queue is to teach new users to make high quality edits. Approving trivial edits that ignore more significant problems is counterproductive to teaching these editors what is and isn't a high quality edit.

tl;dr: The marginal value that edits like these add to the post is outweighed by the time it wastes in the review queue, making these edits in fact useless. This is ***not*** appropriate use of the edit system.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78842/discussion-on-answer-by-sphanley-user-is-making-repeated-trivial-edits-that-don).

Comment: @GEOCHET Please stop making trivial edits; whether you're trying to prove a point, or just trying to troll the OP; or doing it for some unknown reason, Please Stop.

Comment: @GEOCHET - All right, your edits and constant flags of George's comment have veered into troll territory. I'm locking this answer to get this to stop.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>, if you have the time/energy to fix things right. You may want to use the trick I sometimes do: make a quick change, then use the grace period to fix it the rest of the way and update the summary accordingly. This is the most accurate option, because Community will reject with the reason that the edit failed to fix major issues with the post. That's the heart of the matter, not the question of whether or not the edit is too minor.

Or <kbd>Reject</kbd>, if it's a particularly obviously bad case. Given that that's what a diamond did here, it seems reasonable enough when there's more of exactly the same type of fix to make just sitting there.

Alternatively, <kbd>Skip</kbd> if you don't feel like fixing it yourself. <kbd>Skip</kbd> is always a correct answer.

Comment: Please don't exploit the "Reject and Edit" button to give yourself single-vote reject privileges, whether or not you *intend* to also edit. There are good reasons to couple the actions for non-moderators, and [you have a period of edit exclusivity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155619/254929) anyway that should make this unnecessary.

Comment: @Air: He isn't abusing it, he's just making sure noone steals the review underneath him while he fixes *everything*. Of course, that 2 minute or so period of exclusivity might/should have been enough...

Comment: @Air: Yeah, I've had too many suggested edits get approved under me while I'm editing in the right edit to consider that this is, in fact, unnecessary.

Comment: If you can't solve *all* the problems right away, at least solve *whatever you can* in the space of a couple minutes so that each of your atomic actions are reasonable and legitimate. Hit "submit" and then continue if/when you need to with another edit, either within the grace period or at your leisure.

Comment: @Air: Well, I won't disagree with that. Making a quick but still reasonable edit and then expanding it would probably be (slightly) better, it's just been difficult to cut it short like that. ;)

Comment: @Air: For completeness, I had this happen to me again just now: I spent 1 minute and 55 seconds after the review loaded fixing the errors before the edit went through under me, and I wasn't really done yet either. (I have a script that records page load times.) Two minutes is therefore clearly neither sufficient nor actually what anyone gets.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I would upvote a feature request to increase the exclusivity period if you care to make it.

Answer (score -33):

Who cares? As long as the edits are not abusive or detrimental, he is providing a net positive with his time.

If you have additional edits that you want to make, then you are also contributing.

In the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8209994) you provide, he fixes a very obvious spelling error in the title. How is that inappropriate or unwanted? It is very common on a crowdsourced site like this for there to be multiple contributions to make something 'complete' or up to 'community standards'.

When we look at the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11803227/revisions) that resulted from the question after all this, what is the major revision that the original editor was missing?

***TL;DR: There is no 'useless' edit. All contributions in a positive direction are useful, no matter how small.***

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78845/discussion-on-answer-by-geochet-user-is-making-repeated-trivial-edits-that-dont).

Comment: "The answer is heavily downvoted and the comments devolved into namecalling. Since the OP continued to engage in said namecalling; it made it necessary to nuke the comments and answer." -- What changed?