# Provide more guidelines for reviewing edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

#### Summary:

The guidelines for what types of edits should be approved are unclear.

#### Details:

The [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) describe the reviewing suggested edits privilege as follows:

> In addition, users with this privilege level can also begin reviewing
> suggested edits (which previously you would have had to suggest).
> These edits remain in a pending state until they get enough votes to
> either approve them and make the edits take effect or reject them and
> discard the edit. Two votes in either direction will finalize the
> action, except on Stack Overflow where three votes are required.

I think this does a good job of explaining the mechanism for how reviews work.  But it doesn't provide any guidance as to what sort of edits should be accepted or rejected.

The reject button provides some feedback by requiring reviewers to pick a reason for rejecting an edit.  And the review audits help by providing examples of edits that should definitely be rejected.

But my observation is that there is a wide range of minor/trivial edits where reviewers have conflicting opinions.  For example [here's an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8210714) that 3 reviewers voted to accept and 2 voted to reject.

I have seen a lot of discussion on meta about reviewing edits and often there is a complaint that many reviewers are too quick to approve edits and simply approve everything.  Today there was a question asking about [trivial edits that don't fix all changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295308/user-is-making-repeated-trivial-edits-that-dont-fix-all-changes) which led to a variety of opinions in the comments and answers in the responses.

The question specifically highlighted a question where an edit was proposed which would [correct the spelling of a word in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8209994) changing it from "Genrate" to "Generate".  After being mentioned on meta the edit was rejected by a moderator for the reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
> easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
> completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Obviously the edit does not "actively harm readability" so the decision must be that the change is "completely superfluous."  However, I would not tend to categorize the change as "completely superfluous" nor would I say that it does not make the post "even a little bit easier to read."  But I do agree that the edit is trivial and I would reject it in accordance with a policy that ["tiny, trivial edits are discouraged."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

When I was writing this question I clicked through a few pending edits in the edit queue and noticed a couple of other example of the same user correcting the spelling of "genrated" to "generated" which were both approved:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8210955
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8211161

After noticing this I did a search for "genrated" and saw that as of the time of my search there were 682 results.  My guess is that this user did something similar and is trying to systematically correct the misspelling of this word.

If behavior such as this is meant to be discouraged then it might be helpful to add something like "too trivial" as a rejection reason.  On the other hand if this is encouraged (as I think it would be on a site like Wikipedia) then it might be helpful to clarify it in the guidelines somewhere since the other meta question I linked to [suggests that what the editor is doing is inappropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295311/937324).

Overall I don't have a proposed solution and from what I've read in meta it looks like managing reviews is a topic of ongoing discussion.  But I thought this example provided a good illustration of the ambiguity of the guidance for conducting reviews, and that perhaps that is something that could be addressed in some way in the future.

Comment: You think the people approving such edits are the same sort of people that read guidelines?

Comment: @TZHX from reading the rejection reasons I would be inclined to approve the edits I liked to in this question.  I agree that simply adding information to the help center would probably not change much, but perhaps add a "too trivial" reason would help calibrate reviewers if trivial edits should be rejected.  I can't speak for others, but I know that would help me know what to do, if that is indeed what is desired.

Comment: The first edit you linked to, what improvement did it make to a year-old zero-score question?

Comment: @TZHX I guess you are right that one probably does fall into the "completely superfluous" category.  When I was looking at the rendered diff I thought it improved the indentation in a trivial way, but on closer examination I see that's not the case.

Comment: [Add “too minor” audits to review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183977/add-too-minor-audits-to-review-queue). I believe I also proposed / read a suggestion to, when you start of reviewing, start you off going through a set of hand-selected posts to guide you in the right direction as to what should and shouldn't be allowed and make sure you actually are getting there (although don't ask me to find that, although maybe I just thought of that now).

Comment: guidelines for edit reviewers are based on those laid out in this FAQ:  [How do I make a good edit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit)

Comment: There are guidelines at meta.stackexchange: [Guidelines for reviewing Suggested Edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/155539#155539)

Answer (score 42):

If you feel strongly that a given edit does not go far enough to improve a post, then you can save the time of other reviewers by immediately rejecting it *and* send a strong message to the author... Just **submit a better edit** using the "Reject and Edit" button.

[image]

For instance, you could've [made these same spelling corrections](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8210955) *and* fixed the grammar while rejecting the edit. The editor would then see:

[image: This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.]

OTOH, if you can't in good faith discard the edit *and* you feel like re-editing the post is too much work for this... **Then it probably isn't actually too minor at all.** Approve it and let everyone get on with their lives.

Answer (score 8):

Not a long time ago, there *was* a "Too Trivial" reason to reject edits. This has been replaced with "No improvement whatsoever", but it continues to be used the same way by the same people. If I had to guess, I'd say the reason for the change was people were sick of seeing this discussion repeat itself.

While changing an `i` to and `I` does make the post more "correct" -- it only does so in the most superficial of ways. It doesn't actually make it any easier to understand, because everyone is so used to seeing it. Saying "fixed grammar" in the summary to this edit, while leaving the rest of it an unintelligible mess, boggles the mind.

In the same way, fixing a single typo that has been on a question for several years does not make a *real* improvement to the question. People reading "lamda" *know* that the user meant "lambda". Doing this and yet leaving the HTML markup that is a core part of a question hidden because the OP didn't indent it *delays* good edits being made -- as edits are locked while the review is waiting.

In the first example you link to, all that is changed is a styling choice. There's absolutely no objective improvement. It would be the same as someone going into your code and changing the spaces to tabs, then asking you to pat them on the back and tell them how much better they made it. Yet, it still got approved by people who's thought process may be more along the lines of answering "no" to "does this edit make the post worse?" rather than "yes" to "does this edit make the post better?"

Trivial edits are not going to go away, because making them is incentivised. They're incentivised to try and reward people for making substantial edits, true, but we are where we are. People will continue reviewing as they do, those who look for improvement will reject those they don't feel does enough and those that look for things getting worse will click "accept" unless they come across one of the far-too-obvious audits.

Comment: The root problem is that EVERYONE wants clear, simple categories into which they can lump all edits, ideally based on simple heuristics. That's understandable - it is the mechanism by which we all default to dealing with complexity. But good edits routinely defy such categorization; the examples cited by the OP are similar in size but differ in their actual benefit.

Comment: @Shog9 I agree. If it could be determined from clear instructions with no room for interpretation, then there'd be no need to involve the monkeys.

Answer (score 8):

The whole system is flawed and needs a serious rethink. Take [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30529193/revisions), for example.

OP titles the question as:

*Stop "Ding" while pressing enter*

Approved edit:

*How can i stop the "ding" sound while pressing enter*

Subsequent edit by a >2k user:

*How can to stop the "ding" sound while pressing enter*

Seriously? For starters, not one single 'improvement' includes a question mark and the final revision is a total abomination as far as the English language is concerned. It will take more than an update to a few guidelines (which no-one will read anyway).

Comment: Not only a subsequent edit, but [a direct "improvement" of the suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8249289) via suggested edits review queue.

Comment: There is my code.  Now all your bases are belong to us?

Answer (score 5):

Any edit that is positive is an important contribution. If people have an objection to there being too many small ("trivial") edits in the review queue, then that is a valid issue to fix, but that in no way negates the positive impact of many small edits to a large body of content.

**After all, if the edit is 'too minor' or 'trivial', you should be editing that post to include your edits and contributions as well, right?**

> "After noticing this I did a search for "genrated" and saw that as of
>   the time of my search there were 682 results. My guess is that this
>   user did something similar and is trying to systematically correct the
>   misspelling of this word."

This is great! Think of all the good someone taking this initiative and effort to improve your site for free represents.

Some efforts are large and in small areas. Some are granular and widespread. Together, they make all the difference in making this site a better site than others.

Comment: Users that require approval for edits should not be making single-character spelling fixes.  One of the considerations here should be "Is this edit substantial enough that it is worth the time of 3 other people to review it?"

Comment: "One of the considerations here should be "Is this edit substantial enough that it is worth the time of 3 other people to review it?"" -- Nope. That is an issue with the system, not with the edit.

Comment: A phrase like "Try to make your edit substantial, because it takes the time of 3 other people to review it" would look really nice on the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) IMO. But ultimately I agree with @GEOCHET, fixig spelling (especially in keywords and tags) improves the search results dramatically and is in no way "too minor to keep". Ideally, someone with 2k reputation should do this to avoid reviews though.

Comment: Agreed totally. Sick of this "omg dont make minor edits we cant take it" nonsense. Improvement is improvement, and the system can take it. Let's argue about the insanely huge close vote queue, not the edit queue, which is never large.

Comment: Well said Lightness. Amazing how conceited people have become just because they can contribute to the queues.

Comment: I agree. I think we need a better system, maybe a queue or something that collects and organizes recent changes and shows the difference between posts, so that high rep users can go through the changes in their free time and approve or reject. Oh wait... we have that already. In all seriousness is there some kind of feature that could be added to help out with organizing edits? Maybe let reviewers only subscribe to certain "edit tags"? I have a hard time believing the only solution is "don't suggest minor edits". Maybe encourage reviewers to skip minor edits if they're not worth their time?

Answer (score 5):

Ok I guess this has been discussed for a while, but I would like to propose a very strong opinion as to trivial edits:

**19 out of 20 edits in my queue are a waste of time.**

Example 1: Fix the grammar of a non-native English speaking poster. Quite often the "fix" is more correct than the original, but itself not correct English grammar either.

Example 2: "I made the code more legible by adding a space here and a new line there"

Such fixes should be rejected. I can buy the argument small improvements to grammar are nevertheless improvements. But on the other hand they are wasting my time - I am a senior level programmer, why am I reviewing first grade English here? To what end? To what purpose?

It takes time for me to figure out whether the edit has broken some code or not, especially those folks who for example like to "fix" code by following their own spacing scheme. These are useless, dangerous, and time-wasting edits. They should be **discouraged in the strongest terms possible**, and we need a consensus on it, or I'll be a lone voice in the woods.

**Why? Because if 19 out of 20 reviews are trivial grammar-nazi or just "my style is better than your style" edits, then I get terribly bored. And when I get bored, I will stop doing it.**

I would argue that these trivial edits, these smallest of small grammar improvements make SO worse by turning off competent people. Competent programmers do not like to do stupid things. And checking whether some trivial grammar improvement on a post breaks things falls under stupid things.

Answer (score 3):

*Since my question was posted for discussion I'll add my own thoughts after from having read several posts related to my question*

### Summary

There is limited guidance for what reviewers should do because of a lack of consensus regarding what edits are appropriate.

### Details

As anyone reading meta likely there are a variety of reasons that people participate on stackoverflow.  One of these reasons is to gain reputation and badges.  Users with less than 2000 reputation are able to gain 2 points of reputation for an accepted edit. At times this encourages users to submit large numbers of relatively minor edits in an attempt to gain reputation quickly.  And this is something that has been asked about on meta before and received various different answers.

#### Arguments for rejecting minor edits

For instance six months ago a user asked ["100 edits in one evening. Is it wrong?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276402/100-edits-in-one-evening-is-it-wrong) Generally the users commenting and answering that question seemed to think that it was wrong, and not something that the community wants to encourage.

A question from 4 years ago (migrated to meta stackexchange) asks ["Some users gaming the edit system by searching for misspelled words"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83557/some-users-gaming-the-edit-system-by-searching-for-misspelled-words).  The [top voted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83559/174160) said:

> Personally, I would have rejected thelot of these edits. I hope our
> 10k users start doing this as well for cases that are clearly not
> going far enough.
>
> Perhaps if there was only one, I would be fine with it. But there is a
> clear pattern here that is disrespectful to the 10k users time.
>
> I see you did reject, that is good. If enough people rejected the
> edits, the user would have been banned from suggested edits for a
> week.
>
> There is a cost to approving edits, attention is not free.

In a more recent post a user asked ["Same one-letter edit suggested to nearly 60 questions. Should I alert a moderator?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289145/same-one-letter-edit-suggested-to-nearly-60-questions-should-i-alert-a-moderato) The users writes:

> On a hunch, I checked the user's activity and found nearly 60
> suggestions in the past ~30 minutes. After spot-checking at least a
> dozen, I determined that every one of these suggestions corrected the
> same typo (and nothing else).
>
> Normally I would approve an edit that corrects a typo; words should be
> spelled correctly, especially important words like the name of a
> language, especially in important places like the title of the post.
> However, this is a clear case of a user querying for some common error
> and then correcting it in bulk without regard for the overall quality
> of the post.
>
> . . .
>
> I'm not asking whether to accept or reject the edits themselves. I voted
> to reject many of those pending edits using the custom "causes harm"
> reason and the explanation . . .

There are more examples that I could cite, but I think this establishes a patterns showing some reviewers want to reject edits from users who attempt to systematically make minor edits, even if the edits themselves improve the site (i.e. by correcting a spelling mistake).

However, this is not necessarily a consensus view as sometimes questions about this activity lead to answers where meta users indicate that this behavior is fine.

#### Arguments for approving minor edits

About a year ago a user asked ["Edit hunting and possible reputation farming - how should I react?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260268/edit-hunting-and-possible-reputation-farming-how-should-i-react) regarding a user who appeared to be systematically correcting posts with the word "conect" in the title.  This time the users answering on meta seemed more sympathetic to the editor and the [top voted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260332/937324) said:

> Obviously, SO's goal is to be a quality content site. Quality content
> means hard work to some extent, like editing and reviewing. On the
> other hand, some edits are considered as "too minor" and thus, the
> reasoning of reviewers is, that even correct edits should be rejected,
> because they are minorish.
>
> Now please stop a moment and think about what we are doing here. We
> sacrifice correctness and quality to an arbitrary limit of minimum
> edited characters. But which of the two actions is leading us towards
> the goal of a quality site, and which is not?
>
> . . .
>
> Bottom line: The last to be blamed is the editor. He has only found an
> efficient way to locate and fix similar problems quickly. Anybody
> could have easily done the same.

Another question from a year ago asked ["“Too minor” edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site) and the [top voted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253512/937324) concludes:

> We should allow people to correct grammar and spelling mistakes. We
> don't have to be obsessive about it, but if someone is willing to
> spend the time for that kind of edit, let them.

There are more questions and answers of this type, but I think these examples show the contrasting opinions between those in favor of rejecting minor edits and those who argue for approving all correct edits (since fixing a spelling mistake is inarguably "correct")

### Conclusion

Although the help pages state that "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged" there is no way to definitively determine what a "trivial edit" really is.  The current review process is biased towards accepting all non-harmful edits since the only guidance about what to reject comes from review audits which use unambiguously bad proposed edits.  And the reject reasons require a user to specify something other than "trivial" when choosing to reject an edit.

Some reviewers apparently use "no improvement whatsoever" as being synonymous with "too trivial" but in my opinion they mean different things and it is technically incorrect to say that correcting a misspelled word offers no improvement whatsoever, even if the changes are insufficient.

However, some users remain suspicious of "minor" edit, especially those made in large numbers by users who are probably doing this in order to gain reputation.  And especially when the edited post still has many problems even after the editor makes some minor correction.

Overall I still think it would be helpful to provide more guidance about the review process, particularly for users for whom this is a new privilege.  But perhaps the disagreement in the community means that it is best handled via discussions on meta for now, for those users who care to ask.

Comment: Good summary thanks - should have read this first. I strongly disagree that minor edits make the site better. Minor edits worsen the signal to noise ratio in the review process and thereby they make the site worse. How many reviewers don't bother to do it anymore? Anyone asked them why? If SO turns into a forum where one side makes mediocre edits and the other side approves mediocre edits, you end up in mediocrity. Keep the quality high!