# What if we allowed 1-point for minor edits?

Tags: discussion

It has been discussed a lot that many edits come through, which don't really deserve the 2 points.

I think that history has shown us that, on average, a passing edit is around at least 5 separate changes.

But what about if I just want to change *one* thing. While it's not that great , it is still something.

We may have many 1-point changes that, on the whole would help more than if we had required only meaty changes.

And maybe I just want to fix that annoying apostrophe mistake, but don't want to capitalize all the "i's",  while Sally wants to capitalize all the "i's" but could care less about possessive grammar.

Answer (score 8):

Editing is not about rep, it's about making the post better.
If you can't be bothered to capitalize the Is but you want to fix a typo, just don't edit. That'll clog the edit review queue for nothing, since another edit will be necessary.

When you have full editing priviledges (>2000 reputation), you can do minor edits since they only have the bumping side-effect---an annoyance, but not terrible. There won't be any rep then, so there is little point to implement your idea in my opinion.

Comment: thanks, the point re: `full editing priviledges (>2000 reputation)` eluded me

Comment: When you have over 2000 reputation, you can edit a post without having to have it peer-reviewed; it takes place immediatly, and grants no reputation. @Coffee

Comment: Although just because you *can* make minor edits doesn't mean it's suddenly a good idea.  Hopefully by that point you know enough to make a good edit, not a minor edit.

Comment: @davidism I agree. I just noted that it was not terrible but an annoyance---should I rephrase?

Comment: All edits are important. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295322/5640

Answer (score 2):

There should be no rep awarded for edits. Edits are something that should be encouraged by the community because people want a site with better content, not because they want more rep.

Anything that gets in the way of edits or makes people complain about or reject 'trivial edits' is in the way of making the site better and should be seriously reconsidered.

Comment: ah, yes... yes, like how Wikipedia runs it. Good idea

Comment: this should be feature request. I buy this

Comment: Except this is how the site used to be.

Comment: the point about `reject 'trivial edits'` really rings true though. Seems sad to put barriers on people who are trying to help

Comment: Well that has been the topic of some discussion recently: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295319/provide-more-guidelines-for-reviewing-edits

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295330/what-if-we-allowed-1-point-for-minor-edits

Comment: Thanks!!! I'm hopeful we can do something here - just need to prepare some more evidence and a decent argument :-)