# Guidelines for new reviewers

Tags: support, review-queues

I'm trying to make sure I understand what should or should not be edited. For example, I've seen that "Thanks in advance" should be removed. However, I can't find this in any guidelines. I've checked the following help pages and question, but have been unable to find anything detailed.

[Access Review Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)

[Proposed Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes)

[Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

[Guidelines for reviewing edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295319/provide-more-guidelines-for-reviewing-edits)

Comment: Did you mean to post this on Meta Stack Overflow or over on Meta SharePoint?

Comment: Just remove *noise* from posts.  "Thanks in advancement" does not improve the readability of the post and is therefore noise.

Comment: [meta-tag:canonical] editing guideline at MSE: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/165773)

Comment: @bluefeet I assumed that editing guidelines would be the same, at least across technical communities

Comment: Okay, so removing noise... Reformatting code, hyperlinks... Fixing spelling/grammar. Anything else you see frequently? And is there anything you see often in the review queue that you reject outright?

Comment: @ErinL Normally, yes. While I'm not too familiar with SharePoint.SE, it's possible they have some editing guidelines specific to that site.

Comment: wrt code, here's a canonical guidance: [When should I make edits to code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155538/194720, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/194720, and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288505/215552.

Comment: You should also check Meta SharePoint to read up on their specific guidelines. There might be some things that are handled differently.

Comment: The fact that someone who actually tried to access this information __couldn't find it__ with considerable effort is concerning to me. Thanks for posting this!

Comment: @enderland It would be great if, the first time a user accesses the review queue, there's a link to guidelines.

Comment: Paul, Glorindel, Luke, Toto, SuperBiasedMan. This question is about "the workings and policies of Stack Overflow," specifically the policies for reviewing and editing questions. This is what the help center states is on topic. The on hold text states, ""This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network." Questions about the workings of Stack Exchange network are on-topic, and this question isn't specific to SharePoint SE. I simply mentioned that site so that no one was confused by my question wrt my reputation on this site.

Comment: @ErinL It might be good to ask this question (rather, have a moderator migrate it) at Meta Stack Exchange instead of Meta SO, to make it clear that you're asking the general network-wide question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If you post your comments as an answer, I'll accept it. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the only way to find these "guidelines" is by looking at the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), yet that doesn't include the information you are looking for. The next would be searching for questions tagged [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edit) (or with s) and ordering by votes. [suggested-edits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/suggested-edits) can be a source of inspiration too. (The above mentioned has to ignore bugs and feature requests.)

Comment: I did a lot of searching (on every term I could think of) before I asked this, on both meta sharepoint and meta stackoverflow

Comment: This is the most helpful link so far, thanks to @Mike McCaughan:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts