# Is an answer which doesn't compile inherently very low quality?

Tags: discussion

I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244998/4723795) which doesn't compile. It's Java fundamentals and in my opinion it's very low quality, but if it gets reviewed by someone who doesn't know Java it could be declined. Should such an answer be flagged or not?

Comment: Flagged as What? If it's wrong or just poor Downvote it and move on.

Comment: Flagged as very low quality as the answer is against language grammar.

Comment: So it's just wrong...

Comment: OK, Understood. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: @gnat thanks for the link. Does each review queue has it's own topic like that?

Comment: you mean, some kind of [meta-tag:canonical] guidance? I'd say yes. [This one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650/839601) is for triage, and some other guides are linked to [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332656/839601)

Answer (score 16):

Answers that are wrong should be down voted, not flagged.

If you can understand that the answer is wrong it isn't very low quality. When a post needs more context / knowledge than just the post to act on a flag, then flagging is probably not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no requirement for code in answer to compile. There is nothing wrong with answering question with half line of code and explanation.

Note that possibility of such answer *may* mean the question is just typo and should instead be closed as such.

To particular question and answer: Question is clearly not a typo so while very basic it is ok to be on SO (especially since it has reasonable MCVE), probably duplicate of existing one. For an answer - I'm not Java expert, but it feels like question was

> why `toString` function did not override `toString`

and answer

> override must be declared as `@Override public String toString(){...` (missing `@Override`).

Adding extra details to answer is nice, but optional. To make it into complete function does not add much value for anyone who is able to write any function in that language. Making it complete into complete copy-paste-ready answer for OP  (like [upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39244942/477420)) actually makes it harder to spot what exactly needed to be done from my point of view.

Note that original version of the answer had `@Override private String toString()` which indeed was wrong answer potentially deserving downvote (but not because it did not compile, which was just symptom of problem). Flagging that version would be wrong (definitely an answer, reasonable quality, not spam) - downvote and/or comment would be appropriate (i.e. fabian provided nice and actionable comment that was edited by OP into the post - "You cannot use any visibility but public with a overridden toString() method.")

Comment: You missed the access modifier which cannot change from public to private in java. Anyway, got your point

Comment: @xenteros indeed, as I said Java is not my thing. I see that original version of the answer did have `private` - and author applied nice comment from fabian to fix it. Original version indeed was wrong answer *potentially* deserving downvote (but not because it did not compile, which was just symptom of problem).