# Should I flag a user that only does minor (incomplete) edits

Tags: discussion, edits

**Situation:**

I've seen 1 particular user make a lot of minor edits (over a course of many days) that are incomplete. This user now has 2000+ rep so his edits don't need reviews anymore, but the first 200/300 edits have been made under 2000 rep (calculated).

**Example:**

```
public void Q()
         {
                               DoSomething();
         }
```

*bunch of text with spelling/grammar mistakes*

---

**Turns in to:**

```
public void Q()
{
                               DoSomething();
}
```

*bunch of text with spelling/grammar mistakes*

---

Note he only moved the brackets, the content still isn't properly indented and there are lots of words/sentences to be edited. Even if you yourself are not good in English you could still format the full code instead of only the brackets.

**Problem:**
If someone under 2000 rep does an edit like that it will likely only get approved by robo reviewers. This behavior is the opposite of what I've been taught about editing on stack overflow and thus should not be allowed. I've already posted a comment on one of the users questions but he keeps on making small useless edits I later on encounter and usually fix.

What should I do in this case? Just let it go because the user is not filling the review queue or flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: Well some say it is too minor and the editor should fix all issues in a post, others say that each improvement is a good edit, even when other issues aren't fix and "too minor" rejection has been removed anyway, so I would skip it. Doesn't look like SO has a clear guideline here.

Comment: @Tom IMHO people under 2k rep definitely shouldn't do those edits as it fills up the review queue. He could leave the grammar/spelling alone too for all I care but only brackets (or comparable stuff) just bugs me

Comment: I agree on that, but the review queue doesn't give you a proper rejection reason anymore (since "too minor" has been removed). You still can try "no improvements", but it's description doesn't match to any "too minor" situation. Or you choose "reject and edit", but this requires more work on your part.

Comment: @Tom That's true, but just because we don't get the option anymore doesn't make those edits "right" (as far as I know). But I do understand your concern. Currently I can't access the review queue yet, but I'll soon be able to

Comment: If you have a more extensive edit, the reviewers should use "Reject and edit", don't waste an opportunity to fix stuff. The reviewers are the ones that are being lazy.

Comment: @Braiam 1. I can't review edits yet :) 2. The reviewers aren't lazy, everyone does this in their time for free. The lazy one is the editor that just wants the dahm gold badge. But I get your point, I usually come across those types of edits and indeed improve them.

Comment: @Braiam Odd that you think not taking the time to fix someone else's mistake for them is the one being lazy, and the person who's benefiting from creating work for other people while adding nothing of value is the one who's not lazy.  The reviewer who takes the time to fix someone else's bad edit is *going above and beyond what's expected of them*, and the editor who's submitting an edit that's causing more problems than it is adding value, just because they personally benefit from that harmful action, is the one being lazy.

Comment: For a user with over 2K rep, if the edit isn't harmful in any way, I'd just let it go. I don't think it helps anyone to bump a post with major issues back to the top of the active queue but the help center only says that trivial edits are *discouraged*. There isn't currently anything on Meta to say that we should take action against users that do this. Unless a moderator posts an answer saying, "Yes, we'd like to know when this happens so we can do something" then I wouldn't do anything.

Comment: @Servy you are a reviewer: just *review*. If you want to reject someone as "too minor" you have to demonstrate what is missing by editing it yourself!

Comment: @Braiam If you can't edit properly you shouldn't in the first place period.

Comment: @Braiam `you are a reviewer: just review.` Sure.  And if an edit is a bad edit because it's not actually adding meaningful value, determining that it merits rejection *is reviewing it*.  If you just want to go around editing posts, then go around finding posts that need editing and edit them, rather than reviewing edits.  If you want to review edits, then you've made the decision to review edits, not just edit posts that someone else couldn't be bothered to edit properly (but submitted an edit for anyway).

Comment: Who's talking about the editor? Read Servy's comment and take it into context. If you are going to reject an edit because it didn't fix all the stuff,**YOU SHOULD FIX THEM YOURSELF THEN**, that's why too minor went away, there's not minor edit.

Comment: @Braiam you're saying edit it yourself, this question is about the EDITOR not the reviewer. And reviewers shouldn't have to re-edit if the first editor could edit properly. And editor had been mentioned multiple times in the comments so don't go saying "who's talking about the editor". Anyway if you just want to argue open a dahm chatroom

Comment: @BSMP good point, this "not harmful" is why I did not flag it yet :)

Comment: If you complain that the editor is doing ignoring the big picture, you can't ignore it too! If you see a post with stuff that needs to be fixed, don't sit on your hands and do nothing about it, fix them, irrespectively how you found the post!

Comment: I recently earned the ability to edit without review (>2k), but IIRC, when my edits went into review, SO has a page explaining not to add "trivial" edits - edits that aren't needed like language translation, misspellings, capitalization, etc. Most of my edits were code formatting changes *more* meaningful that the OP's example and were accepted. But nowadays my reviewing is mostly like my behavior previously - I reject many language-only edits unless they actually add something. Reject and Edit? I reserve that for an edit that does add something but is IMO incomplete.

Comment: @dfd if the edit adds something actually you should use Improve edit. Reject and edit is for "[i]f you feel strongly that a given edit does not go far enough to improve a post", otherwise ["if you can't in good faith discard the edit and you feel like re-editing the post is too much work for this... **Then it probably isn't actually too minor at all**. Approve it and let everyone get on with their lives."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295322/792066)

Comment: if one suggests to change one occurrence of "i" to an "I" leaving the other occurrences untouched, I clearly *reject* the suggestion. Sometimes I "_reject and edit_", but not always, depending on the amount of work required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reject reason reads:

> **no improvement whatsoever**
>   This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

If a question has some severe problems and an edit *does nothing to address those problems*, then that's "no improvement whatsoever". You can make all the minor improvements to a code snippet you want, but if the question is unclear (or otherwise off-topic) then no (minor) edits to the code will change that (and if the question is already closed [it may actually do more harm than good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4/348595#comment469713_348595)).

In other examples the edits may be more helpful; editing badly formatted code *is* useful. But if it's just editing one tiny aspect of the code while leaving a lot of problems intact then it's obviously not really improving anything; I would also reject this for the same reasons.

In your particular example, it's just changing stuff from code style A to code style B (indenting the braces like that is used in some code styles), so that would be a valid reject reason on its own.

---

Should you flag this user? Difficult to say, as I only have one example to go on. It depends on the value of their edits as well as the frequency of them. Some of their edits – even small ones – may be more useful.

I *have* flagged users for consistently making bad edits once or twice, and those flags have been marked "helpful". I *probably* wouldn't bother with this particular user though (especially since they already passed the 2k rep limit).

Comment: Wasn't really talking about reject as I can't review edits yet. But your last part about flagging was helpful +1

Comment: Oh, didn't even notice that @EpicKip. Nonetheless, it is relevant here, because before establishing whether or not a user should be reported, we should first establish whether or not this users behaviour is appropriate ;-)

Comment: That is true indeed!