# Why isn't the edit-system more open?

Tags: discussion

The edit system, on the whole, seems a little bit clunky.

Does anyone else agree? It's not that people aren't editing, and good edits aren't rewarded. It's just that overall I get the sense that we may be putting up obstacles to otherwise simple edits(i.e why shouldn't I be allowed, even as a new user, to capitalize a few "i's" ).

Is the points-system flawed? Why do we gamify the edit system, by giving 2 points for a good edit?

An edit should be something genuine, i.e - I am editing because I *truly want to edit this* , not because you dangle 2 points by my head.

I think the edit system should be revamped. Edits should be something people do because they want to do it.  It should be more seamless, so that good edits can quickly get in and bad edits can quickly be kicked out.

That's the summary of it: as it stands 2 points is too heavy a reward for fixing a few misspellings . It should not be 2 points, considering that you get 5 points for a solid well written question. Too many people are relying upon edits to up their rep, and this effort is not really genuine if they're just making trivial edits.  They need to be answering questions.

Also, should we not take a glance at how Wikipedia does business? They are very similar to us, but one key difference is how they approach edits. Edits are encouraged, and possible for drive-by users to accomplish(of course, they get vetted)

Comment: I think that posters should be more diligent about fixing their own posts.  Sometimes it feels like copy editing is all I do around here.

Comment: _because I truly want to edit this_ - Does anyone "truly want" to spend their time editing questions instead of asking or answering them?

Comment: Work towards getting yourself 2K rep. After that, your edits will be rep-free. Problem solved.

Comment: Considering the attitude of people who spend hours suggesting trivial edits to get rep, I'd rather not have them post answers, thank you very much.

Comment: @BSMP Most people making edits are doing it because they want the quality of the content on the site to be better, rather than because they want to be given 2 rep for making an edit.  This is made evident  by the huge number of edits made by 2k+  users.  They're doing it because they want to improve the post, rather than because they want the rep.  You're right though, most of those users aren't doing it because the act of editing is inherently enjoyable, but rather that the feeling of making the site better is enough of a reward.

Comment: Shouldn't we be doing *everything* because we want to, rather than for rep?

Comment: "Considering the attitude of people who spend hours suggesting trivial edits to get rep" -- The real problem demonstrated. What is a 'trivial edit' other than subjective nonsense?

Comment: @GEOCHET It's an edit that doesn't add value.  The fact that it's a concept too hard for you to understand doesn't make it nonsense.  Being a value judgement, it is of course subjective to a certain degree.  The fact that you subjectively feel that certain edits are of enormously more value than other people doesn't make their judgement wrong.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, at least it's recognized through another badge... :)

Comment: OK, now I'm curious: Did people downvote because they disagreed or did they downvote because it's a duplicate?

Comment: @BSMP I'm curious as well. Most of the downvotes came before I VtC'd (I think it was at -10 when I voted, and I was the first close vote). The score is interesting considering that the dup target seems to be pretty popular (although not without contention): it currently has 178 upvotes and 41 downvotes.

Comment: "It's an edit that doesn't add value." -- Except that is not true. You have repeatedly defined typo corrections as 'useless', which is not true. They add value as well. You only rail against them because the system places needless burdens and overhead on them/you.

Comment: @BSMP  - I think I might have enemies ??? : \  I dunno, I guess  I sound too snarky at points

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Hmm, touche . Maybe your comment implies that dropping the rep gained to smaller number would be the answer. 0.5 rep anyone ?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Well, Duncan sounds like an old philosopher in a classroom, and I sound like ...well, sound a little different :P  If you read aloud you'll see. tone ... such things

Comment: You'd have to also drop the maximum amount of rep you can get overall from edits too.

Comment: @BSMP - Hmm, wait - actually that's the easy answer to this mess!!! Cap the rep gained from edits. At **200 points** - why? Because after 100 edits you naturally love the duty

Comment: I really don't see this as a dupe though.

Answer (score -12):

I agree with the need to simplify the system. There are too many people apparently rejecting edits not because of the merit of the edit, but because of the obstacles that the system puts in place.

A great example of many people: [User is making repeated trivial edits that don't fix all changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295308/user-is-making-repeated-trivial-edits-that-dont-fix-all-changes)

Comment: Any example of such a rejected edit? Because from where I stand, there are too many people *approving* suggested edits.

Comment: Yes, look at the recent edit questions on this site.